# regex - more than 10 characters

Tags: python, regex

How do you indicate a regex that you want to require more than 10 characters?   I know that '*' is more than 0, and that '+' is more than 1 but what is syntax for requiring more than 10?  Thanks all!!!!

Comment: If you want to practice your regex or even just see what a regex is doing, this is a great site. It will break the expression down and tell you exactly what it's expecting. http://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You use brace notation. For instance, the regex `a{10,}` would match 10 or more `a` characters. `a{10,20}` would match at least 10 and no more than 20 `a`s.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what your regex looks like, but this probably will work:

```
[^stuff]{10,}
```

- `{10,}` matches at least 10.
- `{,10}` matches at most 10.
- `{10,15}` matches between 10 and 15.